# Visual Studio 2015 and Taywee/args library compilation issues

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

I'm having trouble compiling the following code in Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition (
First I'm talking about this library : https://github.com/Taywee/args

```
#include <iostream>
#include <args.hxx>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
     args::ArgumentParser parser("This is a test program.", "This goes after the options.");
     args::HelpFlag help(parser, "help", "Display this help menu", {'h', "help"});
//Honestly, the code doesn't really matter.
    return 0;
}
```

(this is the default example in the repository's main page)

[image: These are the settings I use to create the project (Win32 Console Application)]

I add the library in the project's path but whenever I try to compile I get over 100 errors (the first is

```
C2653   'Validators': is not a class or namespace name  console_args_test   D:\dev\lib\args\args.hxx    585
```

I'm running windows 10 x64 and the application build is 32bit.
This is probably an issue with my settings. I probably need to set some flag or something but i have no idea where to look.

BTW, for what it's worth, everything works fine with gcc on the same system.

Comment: Can you add `using namespace args;` and see if that works? It appears the compiler cannot resolve `Validators` which I assume is in `args::`.

Comment: @jessehouwing : You mean add it in main() ? It doesn't really matter what I have in main(). The issues appear when it tries to compile the args.hxx file. I could have a black program and it would produce the same errors.

Comment: Before main, after #includes, insert `using namespaces args;` it could also go in main, but I just want to know if this works.

Comment: @David Thomas : Nope. Same thing. BTW here's a pastebin with all the errors : http://pastebin.com/uwB4MQGv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this was an issue with code order. Intel C++ Compiler had a similar issue. [It was fixed in this pull request](https://github.com/Taywee/args/pull/8)